# Writing an sql statement

Tags: text, boolean, subquery, type-conversion

I am having issues with this SQL statement that I have to write.

The description is

> Write a query that returns all banks with an “insured” date on or after 2000-01-01. Add this query to your SQL file and also generate it’s query plan and add that to your file. Recall from history class, that the federal government insuring bank deposits during the Great Depression. This means that our dataset will show many banks with an insured data of 1934-01-01.

I am getting confused on the great depression part..

Here is the table that I am using

Table `what.banks`:

```
      Column      |         Type          | Modifiers 
------------------+-----------------------+-----------
 id               | integer               | not null
 is_active        | boolean               | 
 name             | text                  | 
 established      | date                  | 
 insured          | date                  | 
 last_updated     | date                  | 
 address          | text                  | 
 city             | character varying(50) | 
 state            | character varying(30) | 
 assets           | numeric               | 
 deposits         | numeric               | 
 ots_region       | character varying(15) | 
 offices          | integer               | 
 offices_domestic | integer               | 
 officies_foreign | integer               | 
 fed_district     | character varying(15) |
```

Comment: Added `postgresql` tag based on the `text`, `boolean` and `numeric` data types.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that part of the question is irrelevant to the specific *technical* question. It is just saying that the oldest insured dates in the data are probably from 1934 and there are likely to be a lot of them. Because you are looking for newer dates, I don't think this is relevant. Personally, I think that context is quite important for effectively working with data.

The reference to the Great Depression is probably a note that federal deposit insurance was invented to prevent runs on banks that led to financial tragedy (this fact seems somewhat relevant to the data in the table).